# onActivityResult is asynchronous and my ProgressBar is not shown

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am starting a `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent from a `DialogFragment` where the user can select files.
When the files are selected, the activity finishes and `onActivityResult` is executed with the result.

In `onActivityResult` I am reading the inputstream of the files which could take a while because some files are downloaded from the internet.

To give feedback to the user I would like to show a determinate progress bar. The problem is that the progress bar is shown after `onActivityResult` is completed. I found this out when I run the debugger.

How can I show a progress dialog while executing `onActivityResult`?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    // TODO Fix no activity available
    if (data == null)
        return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                final ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                if (clipData != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                        final ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                        addAttachment(item.getUri());
                    }
                } else {
                    addAttachment(data.getData());
                }
            }
    }
}


private void addAttachment(Uri uri) {
    File file;

    String filePath = AttachmentUtils.getPath(getContext(), uri);
    if (!Utils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
        file = new File(filePath);
    } else {


        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Bezig met downloaden");
        progressDialog.show();

        file = AttachmentUtils.getFileFromStream(getActivity(), uri, progressDialog);

        progressDialog.hide();

        return;
    }

   //some more code where I do things with the files after download

}
```

Comment: Could you paste the code from `onActivityResult` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to download from server it is required to do those taks inside background thread. Fot this, initiate an AsyncTask object and do as below

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dlg = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        dlg.setMessage("Loading....");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    dlg.dismiss();
    if ( result instanceof Exception ) {
        // show error message
    } else {
        // display data
    }
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

    try {

    // return data;
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return e;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

check wether below call running on ui thread or another thread. Hide the progress bar dialog end of the  `getFileFromStream`. Do not call in very next line.

> AttachmentUtils.getFileFromStream(getActivity(), uri, progressDialog);

Comment: Well I'm just calling `context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` directly. Should I do this inside a AsyncTask?

Comment: yeah... thats best way to do. If your uri is clean nad clear

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
// TODO Fix no activity available
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
if (data == null)
    return;
switch (requestCode) {
    case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Bezig met downloaden");
    progressDialog.show();


        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            final ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                    final ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    addAttachment(item.getUri());
                }
            } else {
                addAttachment(data.getData());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
}
}


private void addAttachment(Uri uri) {
File file;

String filePath = AttachmentUtils.getPath(getContext(), uri);
if (!Utils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
    file = new File(filePath);
} else {



    file = AttachmentUtils.getFileFromStream(getActivity(), uri, progressDialog);


    return;
}

 //some more code where I do things with the files after download

}
```

Hope this help